# Box2D & XNA Rendering the data

Tags: c#, xna, box2d

So i have been finding that for Box2D your physics information should not be your rendering information

so you can't do things like

spriteBatch.Draw(mazeBox, mazeBody.Position / 0.01f, Color.White)

instead you should create transforms of the physics info and use that as your rendering.

So what does that exactly mean? I have been trying to find info on how to use transforms and render but i am getting blanks.

Answer (score 0):

That means that physics could be rendered just as you wish: bigger, smaller, rotated, translated and so on. You just need to find out which proportions your renderer (in our case it's XNA) will draw your physic bodies. Just do the next: draw a line at ground position and a 1x1 box in the ball / box position using "hello box2d" application (this one doesn't exists at all, but you can simply create a new box2d application, which does nothing but simulating ball / box falling on the floor. And do not forget about stepping your physics!).

If you're interested, here's my SFML application with box2d and some character controller basics:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Animation.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Box2D.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-system.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-window-s.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-graphics.lib")

#define M_PI 3.14f

#define PIXELS_PER_METER 64.f
#define METERS_PER_PIXEL (1.f / PIXELS_PER_METER)

#define PPM PIXELS_PER_METER
#define MPP METERS_PER_PIXEL

#define x_cor 2.f * METERS_PER_PIXEL
#define y_cor METERS_PER_PIXEL

// Thanks to bobasaurus =)
class DebugDraw : public b2DebugDraw
{
public:
    DebugDraw(sf::RenderWindow *renderWindow)
    {
        window = renderWindow;
    }

    void DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2 *vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color &color)
    {
        sf::Shape polygon;

        for (int32 i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
            b2Vec2 vertex = vertices[i];
            polygon.AddPoint(vertex.x * PIXELS_PER_METER, window->GetHeight() - (vertex.y * PIXELS_PER_METER), sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0), B2SFColor(color));
        }

        window->Draw(polygon);
    }

    void DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2 *vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color &color)
    {
        sf::Shape polygon;

        for (int32 i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
            b2Vec2 vertex = vertices[i];
            polygon.AddPoint(vertex.x * PIXELS_PER_METER, window->GetHeight() - (vertex.y * PIXELS_PER_METER), B2SFColor(color)); //need transparant outline?
        }

        window->Draw(polygon);
    }

    void DrawCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Color& color)
    {
        sf::Shape circle = sf::Shape::Circle(center.x * PPM, window->GetHeight() - (center.y * PPM), radius * PPM, sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, B2SFColor(color));
        window->Draw(circle);
    }

    void DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Vec2& axis, const b2Color& color)
    {
        sf::Shape circle = sf::Shape::Circle(center.x * PPM, window->GetHeight() - (center.y * PPM), radius * PPM, B2SFColor(color));
        window->Draw(circle);
    }

    void DrawSegment(const b2Vec2& p1, const b2Vec2& p2, const b2Color& color) {}

    void DrawTransform(const b2Transform& xf) {}

private:
    sf::RenderWindow *window;

    sf::Color B2SFColor(const b2Color &color)
    {
        sf::Color result((sf::Uint8) (color.r * 255), (sf::Uint8) (color.g * 255), (sf::Uint8) (color.b * 255));

        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow *App = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML + Box2D Test");
    App->UseVerticalSync(true);

    // ================= Init Physics ====================
    b2World *world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f), true);

    DebugDraw *debugDraw = new DebugDraw(App);
    debugDraw->SetFlags(b2DebugDraw::e_shapeBit);
    world->SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);

    // Define the ground body.
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f * x_cor, 0.0f * y_cor);

    b2Body* groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;
    groundBox.SetAsBox(500.f * x_cor, 10.0f * y_cor);
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox, 0.0f);
    // ====================================================

    // ====================================
    /*b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(5.f * x_cor, 5.f * x_cor);

    b2FixtureDef fd;
    fd.shape = &shape;
    fd.density = 1.0f;
    fd.friction = 0.3f;
    fd.restitution = 0.7f;

    b2BodyDef bd;
    bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bd.angle = M_PI / 4.f;
    bd.position.Set(10.f * x_cor, 80.f * x_cor);
    b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&bd);

    body->CreateFixture(&fd);*/

    b2BodyDef bd;
    bd.position.Set(3.0f, 5.0f);
    bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bd.fixedRotation = true;
    bd.allowSleep = false;

    b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&bd);

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(0.25f, 0.25f);

    b2FixtureDef fd;
    fd.shape = &shape;
    fd.friction = 20.0f;
    fd.density = 20.0f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fd);
    // ====================================

    sf::Image Image;

    if (!Image.LoadFromFile("moo.jpg"))
        return 1;

    //Image.Copy(Image, 0, 0, sf::IntRect(0, 0, 67 * 5, 68));

    sf::Animation Sprite(Image, 45, 50, 5);
    Sprite.SetLoopSpeed(20);
    Sprite.Play(0, 4);
    Sprite.SetBlendMode(sf::Blend::Alpha);
    Sprite.SetCenter(Sprite.GetSize().x / 2, Sprite.GetSize().y / 2);

    while (App->IsOpened())
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        static std::vector<sf::Vector2f> points;
        static sf::Color cl;
        bool nonConvex = false;

        while (App->GetEvent(Event))
        {
            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App->Close();

            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                if (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape)
                    App->Close();

                if (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::W && abs(body->GetLinearVelocity().y) < 1.0f)
                    body->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(0, 5 * body->GetMass()), body->GetWorldCenter());
            }
        }

        {
            if (App->GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A) && abs(body->GetLinearVelocity().x) < 5.0f)
            {
                body->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(-30 * body->GetMass(), 0), body->GetPosition());
            }
            if (App->GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D) && abs(body->GetLinearVelocity().x) < 5.0f)
            {
                body->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(30 * body->GetMass(), 0), body->GetPosition());
            }

            if (App->GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))
            {
                //if (Sprite.IsStopped())
                {
                    Sprite.FlipX(false);
                    Sprite.Play(0, 5);
                }
            } else
            if (App->GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))
            {
                //if (Sprite.IsStopped())
                {
                    Sprite.FlipX(true);
                    Sprite.Play(0, 5);
                }
            } else
            //if (!Sprite.IsStopped())
            {
                Sprite.Play(12, 22);
            }
        }

        world->Step(App->GetFrameTime(), 1024, 1024);
        world->ClearForces();

        App->Clear();

        // And draw all the stuff
        world->DrawDebugData();

        Sprite.Update();
        Sprite.SetPosition(body->GetPosition().x * PPM, App->GetHeight() - (body->GetPosition().y * PPM));
        App->Draw(Sprite);

        App->Display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a Body that represents a rectangle, the following c# code will render a texture according to the Body's physics:

```
spritebatch.Begin();
spritebatch.Draw(texture,
        Body.Position * Scale,
        textureSourceRectangle,
        Color.White,
        Body.Rotation,
        new Vector2(textureWidth / 2f, textureHeight / 2f),
        1f,
        SpriteEffects.None,
        0);
spritebatch.End();
```

Scale is defined for me as 100.0f, meaning that a Body with Height set to 0.1f is equal to 0.1f * 100.0f = 10 pixels. 
The same goes for Body.Position. (0.1f, 0.1f) in box2D is equal to (10,10) in screen coordinates.

It's also important to set the Origin to the center of the rectangle when drawing. This way the rotation happens around the center of your texture.